# font-lock-keywords weirdness

Tags: font-lock

I am trying to modify `pandoc-template-mode.el` to deal with `$$` which is an escape sequence for literal `$` inside the Pandoc template. I have added the `"\\$\\$"` at the top but I still get bad font highlighting as if it were hitting last case of the function.

The modified `pandoc-template-mode.el`:

```
(defvar pandoc-template-font-lock-keywords
  '(("\\$\\$"
      (0 font-lock-keyword-face))
    ("\\$--.*"
      (0 font-lock-comment-face))
    ("\\(\\$\\)\\(if\\|for\\)(\\([^)]+\\))\\(\\$\\)"
      (1 font-lock-preprocessor-face)
      (2 font-lock-keyword-face)
      (3 font-lock-variable-name-face)
      (4 font-lock-preprocessor-face))
    ("\\(\\$\\)\\(endif\\|endfor\\|else\\)\\(\\$\\)"
      (1 font-lock-preprocessor-face)
      (2 font-lock-keyword-face)
      (3 font-lock-preprocessor-face))
    ("\\(\\$\\)\\(sep\\)\\(\\$\\)"
      (1 font-lock-preprocessor-face)
      (2 font-lock-builtin-face)
      (3 font-lock-preprocessor-face))
    ("\\(\\$\\)\\([^$]+\\)\\(\\$\\)"
      (1 font-lock-preprocessor-face)
      (2 font-lock-variable-name-face)
      (3 font-lock-preprocessor-face))
     )
  "Keyword highlighting specification for `pandoc-template-mode'.")

 ;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode pandoc-template-mode fundamental-mode "Pandoc-Template"
  "A major mode for editing Pandoc-Template files."
  :syntax-table text-mode-syntax-table
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults
              '(pandoc-template-font-lock-keywords))
  (setq-local comment-start "$--")
  (setq-local comment-start-skip "\\$--[ \t]*")
  (setq-local comment-end "")
  (setq-local comment-end-skip "[ \t]*$"))

(provide 'pandoc-template-mode)
```

The test file with bad highlighting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?aid style="50" type="snippet" readerVersion="6.0" featureSet="513" product="8.0(370)" ?>
<?aid SnippetType="InCopyInterchange"?>
<Document DOMVersion="8.0" Self="pandoc_doc">
    <RootCharacterStyleGroup Self="pandoc_character_styles">
      <CharacterStyle Self="$$ID/NormalCharacterStyle" Name="Default" />
      $charStyles$
    </RootCharacterStyleGroup>
    <RootParagraphStyleGroup Self="pandoc_paragraph_styles">
      <ParagraphStyle Self="$$ID/NormalParagraphStyle" Name="$$ID/NormalParagraphStyle"
          SpaceBefore="6" SpaceAfter="6"> <!-- paragraph spacing -->
        <Properties>
          <TabList type="list">
            <ListItem type="record">
              <Alignment type="enumeration">LeftAlign</Alignment>
              <AlignmentCharacter type="string">.</AlignmentCharacter>
              <Leader type="string"></Leader>
              <Position type="unit">10</Position> <!-- first tab stop -->
            </ListItem>
          </TabList>
        </Properties>
      </ParagraphStyle>
      $parStyles$
    </RootParagraphStyleGroup>
    <RootTableStyleGroup Self="pandoc_table_styles">
      <TableStyle Self="TableStyle/Table" Name="Table" />
    </RootTableStyleGroup>
    <RootCellStyleGroup Self="pandoc_cell_styles">
      <CellStyle Self="CellStyle/Cell" AppliedParagraphStyle="ParagraphStyle/$$ID/[No paragraph style]" Name="Cell" />
    </RootCellStyleGroup>
  <Story Self="pandoc_story"
      TrackChanges="false"
      StoryTitle="$if(title-prefix)$$title-prefix$ – $endif$$pagetitle$"
      AppliedTOCStyle="n"
      AppliedNamedGrid="n" >
    <StoryPreference OpticalMarginAlignment="true" OpticalMarginSize="12" />

<!-- body needs to be non-indented, otherwise code blocks are indented too far -->
$body$

  </Story>
  $hyperlinks$
</Document>
```

The issue is that on the 6th line of the template above (`<CharacterStyle Self="$$ID/NormalCharacterStyle" Name="Default" />`) the $$ is matched and colored but then the rest of the text should be uncolored. What actually happens is that the rest of the text after `$$` is colored as if the last rule of the function matched as well.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "bad font highlighting as if it were hitting last case of the function".  Which last case of which function?  In which sense is it "bad"?

Comment: @Stefan I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the last font-lock rule still matches, and of its 3 highlighting instructions, the first (that which highlights the opening `$`) won't be applied because this chars has already been highlighted by the first rule, but the other 2 highlighting instructions are still applied because that part of the text hasn't been highlighted yet.

There are also "tricky" cases such as:

```
$sep$$sep$
```

or

```
$$sep$sep$sep$$
```

where the `$$` isn't "an escaped `$`".  Maybe the best way to deal with it is to consider `$...$` as a kind of "string":

```
(defvar pandoc-template-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((st (make-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?$ "\"$")
    st))
```

and then in your rules you'll want to use things like:

```
 ("\\(\\$\\)\\(sep\\)\\(\\$\\)"
  (2 (if (save-excursion (nth 3 (syntax-ppss (match-beginngin 2))))
         font-lock-builtin-face)
     prepend))
```